# Maven multi-module project and Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, multi-module

I have the following projects organized in a flat structured way:

```
parentProject
+-pom.xml

projectWeb <depends on libraryA and libraryB>
+-pom.xml

libraryA
+-pom.xml

libraryB
+-pom.xml
```

The pom.xml inside the parentProject has references to the other modules and its used for inheritance and dependencyManagement, here is a snippet:

```
<project>
    ....
    <modules>
        <module>../projectWeb</module>
        <module>../libraryA</module>
        <module>../libraryB</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
    ...
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
    ...
    </build>
    ....
</project>
```

In **Jenkins** I have one maven job for each project, and it works fine when I build the parentProject, ie. builds every project referenced in the `modules` section.
The problem that I have is when I commit to the SVN a change in `libraryA`, I would expect that after building libraryA, a rebuild to `projectWeb` to be launched, but that didn't happen. 
Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When I remove the `modules` section from `parentProject\pom.xml`, it works as espected, but I loose the aggregation advantage of having a parent pom.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking your parent POM to do two things:

1. Set up dependency management stuff
2. Aggregate your build

It's generally better if you split this out into two poms - a parent pom for #1 and an aggregate pom for #2. You'd then have something like..

```
[root dir] aggregate pom.xml
+ /parent 
+ /web
+ /libA
+ /libB
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301162/211993

You'd then configure Jenkins to check out the root dir and run "mvn clean install"

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why "It's generally better if you split..."? I'm not saying it's not but I don't understand why it is better. Unfortunately I did not understand it from the answer you've linked to. Thanks!

Comment: So, initially, it just helps with separation of concerns - the aggregator is responsible for the order in which modules are built, the parent is responsible dependency versions and things like scm connection details.

Comment: Also, I've seen examples where people have broken down their parent pom into common parts, which then become the parents for other parent poms. Say, for example, you've a couple of projects that use Hibernate, you can pull that bunch of versioning into a hibernate parent pom, and then use that as a "super parent" (as it were, I just made that phrase up) giving you consistent versions of the hibernate library across multiple projects that aren't otherwise linked. But make sure you actually want that shared approach; you're coupling multiple projects together which might not be desirable.

Comment: Or, you might break is into a bunch of super-parents that never get shared, you just do it for readability. To be honest, I've never taken it further than the single parent and single aggregator, but I do find that's a lot cleaner than the parent and aggregator in one.

Answer (score 0):

This should be configured in jenkins job. See "libraryA job"/"Configuration"/"Build Triggers"/"Build after other projects are built"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I put in the edited question, If I remove the modules from the parent pom, the builds are triggered as expected, ie, if I build `libraryA` then `proyectWeb` is builded automatically, without the configuration you mentioned.